# VueJS define global function for child components

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Can someone help me out configuring a global function that I can call in all my Vue files?

When there is this in my Vue file:
`@click="ModalShow.show('my-create')"`

In the `app.js` I defined this constant:

```
const Modals = {
    show(screen) {
      alert(screen);
      // other logic that i implement that should be triggered
    },
};
```

But I keep getting:
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ctx.Modals.show')`

What am I missing? It's a Vue project with the composition API

Comment: You can create a vue plugin for such extensive use. And als check `useModal()` type design pattern. You can inspire from `useRoter()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html), first provide your function to your child components from the app (or parent component)

```
const Modal = {...}
const app = createApp({})
app.provide('Modal', Modal)
```

Then inject it into your component

```
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const Modal = inject('Modal')
    return { Modal }
  }
}
```

Or via script setup:

```
<script setup>
import { inject } from "vue";
const Modal = inject("Modal");
</script>
```